# Insert char like 'Š' in MySQL with PHP

Tags: character-encoding, escaping, character

i have this query:

```
insert into orders (customers_id, customers_name) values ('51064', 'Šample Šample')
```

If i execute this query from PHP, my database record become

```
[51604, '?ample ?ample'] (if executed with MySQLi) or 

[51604, '&Scaron;ample &Scaron;ample'] (with mysql_query)
```

I also noticed that if i use the value from $_GET

```
insert into orders (customers_id, customers_name) values ('51064', {$_GET['name']})
```

it becomes [51064, 'Åample Åample']

**BUT** if i insert manually the query using software like 'Navicat' it saves the query with the correct character (so i think that the charset is the right one)

I need to save the character Š (and many others) in the right way **from PHP**.

Comment: [ensure database charset and tables use same charset throughout, inspect this in phpmyadmin for example...][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7969943/2218934

Answer (score 0):

Set the charset to be used when sending data back and forth from the database server.

```
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")
```

This is preferred over

```
// Will not affect $mysqli->real_escape_string();
$mysqli->query("SET NAMES utf8");
```

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php and http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.charset.php

Answer (score -1):

set Mysql  encoding before using the DB.

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

OR use the utf8  `utf8_encode()`  `utf8_decode()` functions