# Special characters cause error while storing text to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing a website that lets you list a piece of property and view it's custom property information page as soon as you click "List Property". Everything works fine unless you add a a special character and then the page echo's get error which is triggered from mysql_real_escape_string failing. How can I get all of the information saved even with special characters?

List Property Page:

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

PHP:

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start(); 
require_once( "./inc/connect.inc.php" );

if(isset($_POST['list'])){
    $user_email = strip_tags(@$_SESSION['user_email']);
    $price = strip_tags(@$_POST['price']);
    $address = strip_tags(@$_POST['street']);
    $city = strip_tags(@$_POST['city']);
    $state = strip_tags(@$_POST['state']);
    $zip = strip_tags(@$_POST['zip']);
    $prop_type = strip_tags(@$_POST['prop_type']);
    $sqft = strip_tags(@$_POST['sqft']);
    $built = strip_tags(@$_POST['built']);
    $bedrooms = strip_tags(@$_POST['bedrooms']);
    $bathrooms = strip_tags(@$_POST['bathrooms']);
    $description = strip_tags(@$_POST['description']);
    $d = date("Y-m-d");

    $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO properties VALUES('', '$address', '$address', '$price', '$address', 
                                                    '$city', '$state', '$zip', '$sqft', 
                                                    '$built', '$prop_type', '$bedrooms',
                                                    'bathrooms', '$description', '$d')");
    $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO properties VALUES('', '$address', '$address', '$price', '$address', 
                                                    '$city', '$state', '$zip', '$sqft', 
                                                    '$built', '$prop_type', '$bedrooms',
                                                    'bathrooms', '$description', '$d')");
    $id = mysql_insert_id($db);
    header("Location: ../property_info/index.php?id=".$id);
    exit();
 }
?>
```

HTML:

```
                    <form action="#" method="POST">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="price" placeholder="List Price">
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="street" placeholder="Street Address">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="city" placeholder="City">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-2">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="state" placeholder="State">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="zip" placeholder="Zip Code">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <select class="col-sm-12" id="prop_type" name="prop_type" data-placeholder="Type of Property">
                                    <option value=""> </option>
                                    <option value="single">Single Family</option>
                                    <option value="condo">Condominium</option>
                                    <option value="townhouse">Townhouse</option>
                                    <option value="multi">Multi-Family</option>
                                    <option value="mobile">Mobile</option>
                                    <option value="land">Land</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="sqft" placeholder="Square Footage">
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="built" placeholder="Year Built">
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <select id="bedrooms" name="bedrooms" data-placeholder="Bedrooms">
                                    <option value=""> </option>
                                    <option value="0">0</option>
                                    <option value="1">1</option>
                                    <option value="2">2</option>
                                    <option value="3">3</option>
                                    <option value="4">4</option>
                                    <option value="5">5</option>
                                    <option value="6plus">6+</option>
                                </select>

                                <select id="bathrooms" name="bathrooms" data-placeholder="Bathrooms">
                                    <option value=""> </option>
                                    <option value="0">0</option>
                                    <option value="1">1</option>
                                    <option value="2">2</option>
                                    <option value="3">3</option>
                                    <option value="4">4</option>
                                    <option value="5plus">5+</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <textarea class="form-control" name="description" rows="3" placeholder="Tell us about your house..."></textarea>
                            </div>
                            <!-- END ADDRESS FORM -->

                            <p>&nbsp;</p>
                            <p class="center">
                                <a href='www.urbanares.com/property_info/index.php'><button class="btn btn-warning" name='list'>List Property</button></a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Property Info Page

Screenshot:

[image]

PHP:

```
  <?php 
    $_SESSION['post_to'] = $_GET['id'];
    if(isset($_GET['id'])){
        $prop_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id'])or die("get error");
        $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM properties WHERE id='$prop_id'") or die("query error");

        if(mysql_num_rows($check)==1){
            $get = mysql_fetch_assoc($check);
        }else{
            print_r($check);
            echo "<h2>Property does not exist!</h2>";
            echo $check;
            echo $prop_id;
            exit();
        }
    }
    ?>
```

phpMyAdmin:

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Please refer this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7965652/saving-special-characters-to-mysql-database

Comment: Still using `mysql_*` functions ?  [It's depreciated !](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/3282633)

Comment: This has nothing to do with the charset (albeit nobody should be using Latin-1 variants anymore). It's just that `mysql_real_escape_string("0")` still is false in boolean context, thus triggers the `or die()` expression. (And yes, read up on parameter binding.)

Comment: Yeah I already tried that post. Still doesn't work

Comment: also Get['id'] should not be equal to zero, it's auto incrimented. i.e. When there aren't any special characters it links to property_info/index.php?id=55

Comment: I've pin pointed the that the code fails on this line

$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO properties VALUES('', '$address', '$address', '$price', '$address', '$city', '$state', '$zip', '$sqft', '$built', '$prop_type', '$bedrooms', 'bathrooms', '$description', '$d')") or die("query error".$description);

The page die's and echos what the user placed in the description box, including any special characters used

Comment: mysql is now depreciated,maybe you can use mysqli

Comment: that's not going to change this error.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by using urlencode($description) and then using urldecode($description) when echoing it on the property page.